# FileTextureProvider only loading files from "Internal"

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to load downloaded `.zip` files containing both `.g3db` and all required textures. It looks like the `.g3db` file is loading fine with `loadModel()` method. But as I can see the `TextureProvider` method called `load()` can only read `Internal` files.

Any ideas how to force `ModelLoader` to use only `Absolute` paths?

**CODE**

*Loading Model*

```
UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();
G3dModelLoader modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);
model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.absolute(modelPath));
```

*FileTextureProvider load() method*

```
@Override
public Texture load (String fileName) {
    Texture result = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(fileName), useMipMaps);
    result.setFilter(minFilter, magFilter);
    result.setWrap(uWrap, vWrap);
    return result;
}
```

*Error when loading textures*

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: /data/user/0/com.app.sample/files/model/flower/flowerTextures.png (Internal)
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:144)
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98) 
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100) 
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:96) 
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.TextureProvider$FileTextureProvider.load(TextureProvider.java:52) 
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model.convertMaterial(Model.java:292) 
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model.loadMaterials(Model.java:268) 
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model.load(Model.java:107) 
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model.<init>(Model.java:102) 
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:54) 
                                                                                 at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:69) 
                                                                                 at com.app.sample.sdk.libgdx.ar.Display$2.call(Display.java:71) 
                                                                                 at com.app.sample.libgdx.ar.Display$2.call(Display.java:62) 
                                                                                 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromCallable.call(OnSubscribeFromCallable.java:48) 
                                                                                 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromCallable.call(OnSubscribeFromCallable.java:33) 
                                                                                 at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) 
                                                                                 at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94) 
                                                                                 at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:222) 
                                                                                 at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) 
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269) 
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: What platform? Android has a lot of file restrictions. You need to read the LibGDX  docs very carefully.

Comment: Yes on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can use `AssetManager` to load files that are stored as internal data. The key to succes was to use `AbsoluteFileHandleResolver()`.

This is how I load my `Model` from custom created folder inside application.

```
private Model loadModelFromFile(File file) {
    AssetManager assets = new AssetManager(new AbsoluteFileHandleResolver());
    assets.load(file.getPath(), Model.class);
    assets.finishLoading();
    return assets.get(file.getPath(), Model.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that in the libgdx docs that for Android you need to have your assets either as a resource or in the assets folder. So there is no point in forcing the loader to use file paths if you have to have your assets in the assets folder for android.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

Comment: As long as I do have these in my assets folder which I don't because I download the files from API. And you cannot download files to assets folder.